# Deployment of node.js app in one step

Tags: node.js, deployment

We just finished developing a node.js application which includes a Restful API and a Mssql database .

I will need to deploy the app in in-house servers of companies having Windows 2008 and windows 2012 environments

What i want to achieve :

- The best case is to make the deployment in an one-step procedure .

What i m currently doing :

- Clone the project in a dir
- Run npm install ( Best case scenario is to have all dependencies in a folder to avoid problems with versions or npm )
- Deploy the db using a script
- Start processes with pm2 process manager

Is there anyway to pack all these steps in a simple step ? 
Something alternative to docker for example ? (I can't use docker because is not compatible with most of the OS )

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to pack all these steps in a simple step ?

Yes. You can write a script that does all of that for you.

Even without writing such a script you can combine the first two steps easily. To simplify the first two steps you could make your project globaly installable with `npm install --global`. You could install your project that is hosted on GitHub just by doing:

```
npm install -g username/repo
```

and it will install your project and all of its dependencies.

You could also use a private package on npm or even a private npm registry for that.

You could install both the start scripts and the db deploy scripts that way as well in a single step, because your module can install multiple executables.

Comment: Can you please get into a bit more detail about the `npm install global` and `npm install -g username/repo' commands ? Do i have to run them from a certain directory ? I runned the commands and all i can find is an empty folder with the project name in C:\Users\%User%